# Why is anime js only playing the first of dynamically "add"ed animations to a timeline?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, anime.js

So
I'm dynamically adding animations to an anime js timeline below :

```
const target = useRef();
const animeRef = useRef(null)       


      animeRef.current = anime
      .timeline({
        autoplay: false,
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        duration: 250 * animationNodes.length,
        complete: () => resetAnimationParams(_actorIdAnimating, _coordsFinal),
      })
      .set(idString, { translateX: -23, translateY: -34, rotateZ: "315deg" });

      animationNodes.forEach((node) => {
        animeRef.current.add(node)
      })

      animeRef.current.play()
```

It works great for the first animationNodes object, but only the first.

for example with the below input, only the first keyframed animation plays.

```
    animationNodes = [
    {
        "keyframes": [
            {
                "translateY": -100,
                "translateX": 40
            }
        ],
        "targets": "#id-0"
    },
    {
        "keyframes": [
            {
                "translateX": 40
            }
        ],
        "targets": "#id-0"
    }
]
```

This is within a react component, and animation ref comes from

```
const animationRef = useRef();
```

EDIT:
I have confirmed there's no effectful code in the complete function by removing it. The result is the same.

EDIT2:
What is being animated:

```
  <img
    ref={target}
    className={styles.CharacterToken}
    alt={""}
    src={props.tokenImage}
  />
```

EDIT3:
So I thought it might be an issue with the animejs timeline - so I refactored for simplification, concatenating all the keyframes. Interestingly, only the first keyframe plays, just like before when we had a timeline. Could my DOM reference be changing after the first keyframe animation?

Full code below.

```
import anime from "animejs";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import actions from "../../../../../../DataHandlers/redux/actions";
import animationsByDirection from "./animationsByDirection";
import styles from "./CharacterToken.module.css";

export default function CharacterToken(props) {
  const target = useRef();
  const [animeRef, setAnimeRef] = useState()
  const animationPath = useSelector((state) => state.UI.animationPath);
  const actorIdAnimating = useSelector((state) => state.UI.actorIdAnimating);
  const coordsFinal = [
    animationPath[animationPath.length - 1]?.x,
    animationPath[animationPath.length - 1]?.y,
  ];
  let didAnimate = false;
  let dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (actorIdAnimating === props.actorHereId && !didAnimate) {
      animateMovement(animationPath, actorIdAnimating, coordsFinal);
    }
  }, [actorIdAnimating, props.actorHereId, animationPath]);

  const resetAnimationParams = (_actorIdAnimating, _coordsFinal) => {
    dispatch(actions.setIsAnimatingtoCoords(undefined, undefined, undefined));
    dispatch(actions.moveActorLocationCombat(_actorIdAnimating, _coordsFinal));
  };

  function animateMovement(
    _animationPath,
    _actorIdAnimating,
    _coordsFinal
  ) {
    let keyframes = []
    _animationPath.forEach((square) => {
      const direction = () => {
        const deltaX = square.x - square.parent.x; // 1, 0, -1
        const deltaY = square.y - square.parent.y; // 1, 0, -1
        if (deltaX === -1 && deltaY === 0) return "north";
        else if (deltaX === 1 && deltaY === 0) return "south";
        else if (deltaX === 0 && deltaY === 1) return "east";
        else if (deltaX === 0 && deltaY === -1) return "west";
        else if (deltaX === -1 && deltaY === 1) return "northEast";
        else if (deltaX === -1 && deltaY === -1) return "northWest";
        else if (deltaX === 1 && deltaY === 1) return "southEast";
        else if (deltaX === 1 && deltaY === -1) return "southWest";
      };
      keyframes.push(animationsByDirection[direction()].keyframes[0])
    });
    setAnimeRef(anime
    .set(target.current, { translateX: -23, translateY: -34, rotateZ: "315deg" }))

    setAnimeRef(anime({
      targets: target.current,
        keyframes: keyframes,
        loop: false,
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        duration: 750,
        // complete: resetAnimationParams(_actorIdAnimating, _coordsFinal)
    }))
  }
  
  return (
      <img
        ref={target}
        className={styles.CharacterToken}
        alt={""}
        src={props.tokenImage}
      />
  );
}
```

EDIT4:
So I refactored again, making the simplest possible version of this. I removed anime js - I'm now just using Web Animation API.

Please see this codepen - https://codepen.io/wjkmartin/pen/YzxzJWJ

I'm trying to make the animations follow each other indefinitely, starting where the last one ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up switching to Web Animation API, but the solution is the same. Also, timelines are not the best approach. If using anime js, I think the 2nd code snippet where anime({}) is called is a better approach.

**Important learning point, is that transforms are not inherently additive- they replace each other.**

The keyframes don't add together, they replace one another.

In my solution below, I add each transform together manually for each animation. I don't know why I thought the accumulation would happen automatically.

Also - after each animation within the chain, I set the transform of the DOM element to the end state of the animation.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import actions from "../../../../../../DataHandlers/redux/actions";
import animationsByDirection from "./animationsByDirection";
import styles from "./CharacterToken.module.css";

export default function CharacterToken(props) {
  const target = useRef();
  const animationPath = useSelector((state) => state.UI.animationPath);
  const actorIdAnimating = 0;
  const coordsFinal = [
    animationPath[animationPath.length - 1]?.x,
    animationPath[animationPath.length - 1]?.y,
  ];

  let dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const animRef = target.current;
    if (animationPath.length > 0 && props.actorHereId === 0) {
      let keyframeEffects = [];
      let xTransformAccumulated = 0;
      let yTransformAccumulated = 0;
      animationPath.forEach((node, index) => {
        function direction(_node) {
          const deltaX = _node.x - _node.parent.x; // 1, 0, -1
          const deltaY = _node.y - _node.parent.y; // 1, 0, -1
          if (deltaX === -1 && deltaY === 0) return "north";
          else if (deltaX === 1 && deltaY === 0) return "south";
          else if (deltaX === 0 && deltaY === 1) return "east";
          else if (deltaX === 0 && deltaY === -1) return "west";
          else if (deltaX === -1 && deltaY === 1) return "northEast";
          else if (deltaX === -1 && deltaY === -1) return "northWest";
          else if (deltaX === 1 && deltaY === 1) return "southEast";
          else if (deltaX === 1 && deltaY === -1) return "southWest";
        }
        const delay = 250 * index;
        const x = animationsByDirection[direction(node)].x;
        const y = animationsByDirection[direction(node)].y;

        xTransformAccumulated += x;
        yTransformAccumulated += y;

        keyframeEffects.push(
          new KeyframeEffect(
            animRef,
            [
              {
                transform: `translate(${xTransformAccumulated}px,${yTransformAccumulated}px) rotateZ(315deg)`,
              },
            ],
            { delay: delay, duration: 250, iterations: 1 }
          )
        );
      });

      let animations = [];
      let promises = [];
      keyframeEffects.forEach((effect, index) => {
        let animation = new Animation(effect);
        animation.finished.then(() => {
            animRef.style.transform =
              animation.effect.getKeyframes()[0].transform;
         
        });
        promises.push(animation.finished);
        animations.push(animation);
      });
      animations.forEach((animation) => {
        
        animation.play();
      });
      Promise.all([...promises]).then((values) => {
        resetAnimationParams(actorIdAnimating, coordsFinal);
        
      });
    }
  }, []);

  const resetAnimationParams = (_actorIdAnimating, _coordsFinal) => {
    dispatch(actions.setIsAnimatingtoCoords(undefined, undefined, undefined));
    dispatch(actions.setAnimationPath([]));
    dispatch(actions.moveActorLocationCombat(_actorIdAnimating, _coordsFinal));
  };

  return (
    <img
      ref={target}
      className={styles.CharacterToken}
      alt={""}
      src={props.tokenImage}
    />
  );
}
```